# What relation is valid for the voltage U6 in the adjacent circuit?

Tags: voltage

I have problem with the question, I always come to other results. Can you help me with this task.

[image: question]

Comment: At least have the courtesy of explaining what you have understood and what, therefore, is your stumbling block. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go in a circle (arbitrary direction) and add all voltages together. If the arrow is pointing in the other direction, subtract, For example

\$ U_6 + U_5 + U_4 - U_3 + U_2 - U_1 = 0\$

It doesnt really matter which direction you go, or which arrow direction you chose to count positive, as long as you do it consistently.

When you solve this for \$U_6\$ you get the correct answer (which is 2).

Answer (score 0):

You know the sum of voltages in a loop is zero, right?

So add the voltages in the loop, and equate it to zero. Then isolate on one side and you're done.

You have to pay attention to the arrows which indicate in which direction the voltages are measured (which side the black lead of the voltmeter would be on vs. the red lead). So, if you start at \$U_6\$, subtract \$U_1\$ and so on around the loop, and equate that to zero.